# C++: virtual function calling parent

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    virtual int func(void) { return 0; }
};

struct B : A
{
    int func(void) { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    A b = B();
    cout << b.func() << endl;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be `1` but as most of you will know its `0`.

what i want to achieve in my actual code is something along these lines.

```
struct A
{
     virtual int operator() (int i);
};
struct B : A
{
     int operator() (int i) { return i*2; }
};
struct C : A
{
     int operator() (int i) { return i*3; }
};
struct x
{
     A test;
};
```

So my container won't be able to tell before hand if it will hold a `A`, `B` or `C`, but should behave differently still.

Is there a way to achieve the functionality as I anticipated it work??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A b = B();`: you're constructing an object of type `A`, using the assignment operator/copy constructor (through copy elision) from a `B` object, but seen as a reference to `A` (which explains why it compiles without errors)

This isn't polymorphism. `b` is still of type `A`. The link to `B` has been lost.

That would do it:

```
A *b = new B();
```

now

```
cout << b->func() << endl;
```

triggers polymorphism/virtual function and yields 1 as expected.

Comment: thanks man, but is there no way of achieving this without pointers? the parent and child objects are all going to be just a class containing functions, no variable members or anything.

Comment: There is no way without pointers or references.

Answer (score 2):

C++ virtual functions only works for references/pointers, which means indirections.

```
A b = B();
```

This creates an object of type A, not of type B. No indirection, therefor only the function in A is called.